# Regex Pattern Need Help Java toString() method

Tags: java, regex

I have a java toString on code generated from XML . We as a company are logging the toString() to logs and I am having trouble making a good regex to mask all the data effectively .
Here is the sample to String

```
String input="com.example.sensitive.info.UserInfo@15b1534[name=User1, clientName=HARVARD LAW SCHOOL, THE, clientId=12345]";
```

expected output

```
com.example.sensitive.info.UserInfo@15b1534[name=User1, clientName=****************, clientId=12345]
```

Can someone help me with a regex that will mask everything up until the last comma(,) before the  next equal =

here is what I tried

```
maskPatterns.add("clientName=(.*?)=");
```

This ends up masking till next = . I cant seem to figure how to have it backtrack to last comma(,) before next equal(=).

Also if anyone has better regex for it I am all ears

Comment: You may probably just use `"clientName=([^,]*)"` or `"clientName=([^,=]*)"`

Comment: there is comma inside the client name it stops after the first one.

Comment: Right, use `clientName=(.*?)(?=\s*,\s*\w+=|\])`. It will work even if the values contain `=`.

Comment: Would `(?<=clientName=).*(?=,\s*clientId)` help? Or is `clientID` not always present as the next parameter in your string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew almost got it. I ended up masking the last comma also.Anyway to skip that comma

Comment: @JvdV good idea but I cant have clientId in regex since that can change as I want this reusable

Comment: I added a solution that masks with the same amount of asterisks as the length of the value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ... and that's the exactly _wrong_ thing to do, since your answer therefore gives away information about what the original client name string might have been `:-)`

Comment: Should the content be between square brackets?

Comment: well in my case it is toString of java class so it ended up being the case but the regex should be agnostic of it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will try to incorporate both into the solution

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for quick demo and detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
clientName=(.*?)(?=\s*,\s*\w+=|\])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6PF9Q/1)

**Details**

- `clientName=` - a literal string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*,\s*\w+=|\])` - a positive lookahead that requires either `]` (`\]` or (`|`) a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces on both ends (`\s*,\s*`), then one or more word chars and `=` immediately to the right of the current location.

Or, if you need the same amount of asterisks, use

```java
String result = text.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|clientName=).(?=.*?,\\s*\\w+=|\\])", "$1*");
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6PF9Q/3).

**Details**

- `(\\G(?!^)|clientName=)`
- `.` - any char but a line break char
- `(?=.*?,\s*\w+=|\])` - up to the first occurrence of

  - `.*?,\s*\w+=` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, a comma, zero or more whitespaces, one or more word chars and a `=`
  - `|` - or
  - `\]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation help me understand the intricacies of how regex works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#replaceAll` here:

```java
String input = "com.example.sensitive.info.UserInfo@15b1534[name=User1, clientName=HARVARD LAW SCHOOL, THE, clientId=12345]";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\bclientName=.*?(\\s*)(?=\\w+=|\\])", "clientName=****************$1");
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
com.example.sensitive.info.UserInfo@15b1534[name=User1, clientName=HARVARD LAW SCHOOL, THE, clientId=12345]
com.example.sensitive.info.UserInfo@15b1534[name=User1, clientName=**************** clientId=12345]
```

Note that the number of asterisks probably should *not* exactly match the number of original characters in the `clientName`.  Doing so would actually be partially revealing the original content, insofar that it would reveal at least the original length of the `clientName` string.

Comment: I also like your idea of changing no of  * and I will try to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example of `maskPatterns.add("clientName=(.*?)=");` I assume that you want the value in capture group 1.

If it should be agnostic of the square brackets for marking the end of the value, but you don't want to match them either, you might use:

```
\bclientName=([^\r\n,=\[\]]+(?:,(?!\h*\w+=)[^\r\n,=\[\]]*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bclientName=` A word boundary, then match `clientName=`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\r\n,=\[\]]+` Match 1+ times any char except `,` `=` `[` `]` or a newline
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `,(?!\h*\w+=)` Match a comma asserting what is directly to the right is not 0+ horizontal whitespace chars, 1+ word chars and an `=` sign
    - `[^\r\n,=\[\]]*` Optionally match any char except a newline `,` `=` `[` `]`
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times to get all occurrences of a comma
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/09YlsV/1)

If the `[` and `]` can also be part of the clientName, you can [omit them](https://regex101.com/r/4dLNDV/1) from the character classes.